# How to use the same condition(replace) in multiple columns of excel using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace some words from a column using pandas
I used the following to do so:

```
df['Column1'] =  [re.sub('string1','string2', str(x)) for x in df['Column1']
```

I have 20 more columns where I need to place the same condition
Is there a way to use this method for all columns together or do I need to separately write similar codes one by one like stated below

```
df['Column1'] =  [re.sub('string1','string2', str(x)) for x in df['Column1']
df['Column2'] =  [re.sub('string1','string2', str(x)) for x in df['Column2']
.
.
.
.
.
df['Column20'] =  [re.sub('string1','string2', str(x)) for x in df['Column20']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with selected columns in list:

```
cols = ['Column1','Column2',...,'Column20']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('string1','string2', regex=True)
```